# how can I start the kubernetes container when I reboot my server computer

Tags: kubernetes

firstly,I success to deploy my kubernetes master node via docker,
then reboot the server,the container is down,is there any idea to auto-run it.

Comment: `kubectl get nodes` to a see if the list of nodes have come up. If they have come up then check for `kubectl get rc`

Comment: there are many stop container when use the 'docker ps -a',my step link---http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/master/

Answer (score 0):

You need the kubelet to start when your computer reboots. Once it starts up, it will run all of the containers stored in manifest files (on your master node, this should include the master components like the apiserver) and will then register itself with the apiserver and be available to run any assigned pods.

Comment: I just build a single master node(http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/master/),    is it correctly to find the kubelet container and then to start it?

Comment: If you are following that guide, you will need to make sure that the bootstrap pieces (docker, etcd, and flannel) are restarted in addition to the kubelet (e.g. the `docker run` command that includes `/hyperkube kubelet`).

Comment: ye, the problem occur in the docker bootstrap, it is always missing when reboot server. I can't find a way to solve it yet so far....

Comment: You should be able to add starting docker to your system initialization, either through a systemd unit or in `/etc/init.d` or the equivalent on your linux system.